# Trigger to build comma separated list of values for insert & update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I want to store all the insert, update and delete operations performed against the database in. The table should look like this:

```
ID       Created          Operation
 1       2012-05-01       INSERT [SomeTable] (ID, Col1) VALUES (1, 'xyz')
 2       2012-05-01       UPDATE [SomeTable] SET Col1 - 'abc' WHERE ID = 1
```

And so on...

Using a trigger on each table, how do I construct the Operation query? Assume that you will not always know the columns in the table causing the trigger, as you may add columns to the table at a later date and don't want to have to go back and rebuild the trigger.

Here might be the start of it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_MyTable_RowInserted ON MyTable
FOR INSERT
AS

DECLARE @columnList nvarchar(4000)

SET @columnList = NULL
SELECT @columnList = COALESCE(@columnList + ', ', '') + [name] FROM sys.columns WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID(N'MyTable')
print @columnList

-- now we have the columns, need to spit out the values that are in the trigger's inserted table

-- then we need to concatenate all of that into a single, syntactically correct SQL string
```

Comment: try this http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/

Comment: Is this for production audit trailing or debugging?  Because [SQL Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is quite good at debugging.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 introduced [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx), which was designed to do exactly this. (IIRC, this feature is only in Enterprise edition.)